# How to iterate reactjs array object ? Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

when I try iterate array of object as below. When I `console.log` first iteration throwing empty array and after that return array of object. I did checking before `map` array of object as in code. Did I miss anything?

**ShipmentDetail.tsx**

```
export class ShipmentDetail extends Component<any, ShipmentInterface> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      detail: [] as any[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getShipmentDetail();
  }

  getShipmentDetail() {
    let { params } = this.props.match;
    params = params.id;
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/shipments/${params}`)
      .then((response: any) => {
        this.setState({ detail: response.data });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>type</TableCell>
            <TableCell>description</TableCell>
            <TableCell>volume</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {this.state.detail &&
            this.state.detail.cargo.map((row: any) => {
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  wewe
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.description}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.volume}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>;
            })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}

export default ShipmentDetail;
```

Here is sample response from `http://localhost:3001/shipments/${params}`

**Sample.json**

```
{
  "id": "S1000",
  "name": "T-shirts(Summer2018) from Shanghai to Hamburg",
  "cargo": [
    {
      "type": "Fabric",
      "description": "1000 Blue T-shirts",
      "volume": "2"
    },
    {
      "type": "Fabric",
      "description": "2000 Green T-shirts",
      "volume": "3"
    }
  ],
  "mode": "sea",
  "type": "FCL",
  "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
  "origin": "Shanghai Port",
  "services": [
    {
      "type": "customs"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `this.state.detail` is defined as an array (`this.state = { detail: [] /*...*/ }`) but it is accessed as an object: `this.state.detail.cargo`

Comment: Which brings us to the error, an empty array doesn't have a `cargo` property, thus returning `undefined`, on which you're trying to use `map`.

Answer (score 2):

You set `this.state.detail` to `[]` which is truthy value, so `this.state.detail` returns `true`, so `map` will fire on `undefined`

Solution is to set `detail` to `null` in `constructor`

EDIT: you can set it to any falsey value such as `0` (zero), `""` empty string, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `NaN` but I'd prefer `null`

Answer (score 0):

Detail in your state is an array, it should be an object. So during the first render empty array does not have cargo, so it is undefined and thus map is not found